# The theory behind western pentatonic scales

Tags: theory, scales

I'm curious about a more in-depth explanation as to why the major and minor pentatonic scales are prevalent in the western music tradition (Yes, i make a claim here that some might consider debatable. Please hear me out).

I did a brief googling and the most common explanations were: "because it's easy" or "because it sounds good", or the likes. It's not that i disagree, but i feel that there probably is more to the theory than that.

For instance, why are the fourth and seventh notes omitted in a major pentatonic scale (in reference to a major diatonic scale)? It makes me wonder since both the fourth and the fifth are perfect intervals, but only the latter is kept. Is it simply because it goes along the vein of a musical tradition revolving around the I-V relationship?

I'm assuming one could argue that the seventh is left out because of the dissonant quality in relation to the root, no?

Could anyone shed some more light on why this is? I like to hear some of your thoughts on this!

Comment: Pentatonic is basically a modern invention, not very prevalent at all.

Comment: Related (YouTube video of Bobby McFerrin demonstrating universal human understanding of the pentatonic scales): https://youtu.be/Hodp2esSV9E

Comment: @Todd Wilcox That was so awesome. Makes you wonder whether those notes are known a priori, or learned.

Comment: @Erik the pentatonic is mathematically so simple that it's hard to see how anybody could “not know it”, any more than you could possibly “not know the number 5”: even somebody who'd never heard the word “five” could still identify that number of items.

Comment: I think the origins go back to native American Indians. Their flutes were in pentatonic, maybe they just made them even intervals. Then likely adapted to western music.

Comment: Outside of that I don't think there is any significance to it.

Comment: This question appears to be two questions. One, what are the tonal qualities of the pentatonic?  Two, why is the pentatonic scale popular?  Suggest that the question be split into two questions so that the two questions can be more clearly answered.

Comment: @NeilMeyer and marhsalcraft, there are [many traditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatonic_scale#Pervasiveness) that use pentatonic scales, including the music of ancient Greece. I don't think it's a narrowly limited or recent phenomenon.

Comment: @leftaroundabout there are languages that lack words for specific numbers, and native speakers of those languages seem not to know the number five.

Comment: @marshalcraft so Africans and east Asians got their pentatonic scales from the Americas?

Comment: @phoog that was kind of my point: even those speakers who don't have a _word_ for the number five still intuitively understand five-ness. That's few enough so basically the visual cortex already “counts” it as a pattern without any of the iterative process that we use to count things (which does become necessary for higher numbers). Likewise, humans seem to grasp pentatonics without any theoretical justification whatsoever.

Comment: @leftaroundabout but linguistics research has shown that these people do not intuitively understand fiveness. There's no evidence that the visual cortex can learn to identify groups of five in the absence of an iterative process to identify that number (to train the visual cortex, if you will). Humans also seem to be able to grasp heptatonic scales without a theoretical basis, so I don't see anything special in that regard about pentatonic scales.  There's no need to have a theoretical basis for a scale to use it, regardless of the number of notes it contains.

Comment: @phoog “linguistics research has shown...” [citation needed]. If you mean the original Sapir-Whorf studies, those are flawed in many ways. Ok, yes, for the cortex speculation I indeed don't have any evidence whatsoever, but I personally find five to be indeed about the limit of objects I can immediately quantify in any picture, without needing to actually count. — As for heptatonic scales: these aren't so widespread. Of course you find diatonic modes everywhere where European culture has left its mark, but for the very different Arabic or Indonesian scales the number 7 seems to be coincidence.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think I was thinking of something from Steven Pinker's *The Stuff of Thought,* but I can't find my copy right now.  There's also the work of Peter Gordon and a paper co-authored by Pinker and Ray Jackendoff, both cited in chapter 5 of Christine Kenneally's *The First Word.* Gordon's work in particular supports my statement. And if Arabic and Indonesian scales having seven notes is coincidental, doesn't that strengthen my hypothesis that it's possible to use scales without having a theoretical basis for them?  At least, it does not weaken it.

Answer (score 9):

A common "academic" description of these two pentatonic scales is *anhemitonic*. Major and minor scales are *hemitonic*, meaning they contain at least one half step (or "hemitone"). Meanwhile, these pentatonic scales are *an*hemitonic because they do *not* contain any half steps.

If you think about the C-major collection:

```
     C D E F G A B C
```

We see half steps between the third and fourth degrees (E and F) and the seventh and final degrees (B and C). So we simply remove the offenders; by removing scale-degrees 4 and 7 (F and B), we create an anhemitonic scale of `C D E G A C`.

As for the minor pentatonic, let's just rotate that early collection to start on A instead of C, giving us an A-minor collection:

```
     A B C D E F G A
```

We again have half steps between B and C and E and F, so we again remove B and F (although this time they're scale-degrees 2 and 6) to create the `A C D E G A` minor pentatonic collection.

---

We can get a bit more advanced here and look at the interval-class content of these two (same) collections. Without getting too specific, when we track all of the different intervals between every single pitch, we see that this particular anhemitonic collection is made up of 4 perfect fifths/fourths, 3 major seconds, 2 minor thirds, and one major third. Note that there are precisely zero half steps (as expected) or tritones. From a set-theory standpoint, the interval vector is <032140>; Hanson's chemical analysis would be p4mn2s3.

Comment: You may want to point out what intervals you are left with when you take out those scale degrees. The [Hanson analysis](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29997/what-is-the-hanson-system-used-for) of the set yields p4m2ns3 which lacks intervals which most would consider dissonant.

Comment: @Dom Interesting point; I'll make an edit. (Though it would be p4mn2s3, no?)

Comment: Thank you both for clarifying. I think Dom is elaborating on what i had in mind, i.e. prescriptive theories that gives further explanations beyond staments like "i enjoy the way it sounds".

Comment: @Richard yep. My hand writing is terrible and I screwed up a m and n.

Comment: If a half-step is a 'hemitone' (which is technically word-wise fine), why is it normally known as a 'semitone'?

Comment: @Tim Your guess is as good as mine; I'm not sure why it isn't "ansemitonic." (Although, now that I type it out, it does look a little too much like "antisemitic.")

Comment: J'ew know, it's a little bit close...

Comment: IMO it's quite backwards to use set theory to derive anything about how tonal Western music has evolved – except perhaps Jazz-descended styles, but certainly not something as basic as pentatonic scales. Most Western music is _not_ sensibly constructed _starting_ from the 12-edo set, although that set of notes can be used to _play_ almost all Western music (or, _approximate_, as I prefer to call it).

Comment: @leftaroundabout- yep.  As you explain in your answer below, at least Western (and arguably, many other traditions, such as Indian) scales were historically derived from the harmonic series.  Whole steps and half steps are a consequence of what steps we chose to use, not the other way around.

Comment: Interesting answer but doesn't answer the question about why the pentatonic scale is prevalent in Western music.

Comment: @pro Yes, I decided to forego that question because it seemed subsidiary to his actual question (i.e., it's not the question in the title).

Comment: With regards to 'A more "proper" term for these two pentatonic scales is anhemitonic.', I think "anhemitonic" would be one of the properties, but it doesn't really define what we call "the pentatonic(s)" as other pitch collections (such as the 5 tones in "9" chord, that's a "dominant" with an added major 9th) are also anhemitonic when laid in the form of a scale. In other words, "anhemitonic" would be "necessary but not sufficient".

Comment: @AlexLopez Fair point. I'll edit accordingly, thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you would want to explain something complete on its own like a pentatonic as part of something more specific and complex as the diatonic scale. How come the first instruments used pentatonic scales before the invention of the diatonic one?

Comment: @Fefo I approached my answer this way because that's how the OP phrased their question, that's all.

Answer (score 7):

The major pentatonic scale is the richest scale that can be rendered above a Ⅰ pedal bass *using only consonances* (in a sense of “consonance” which I'll elaborate). For example on C,

- C: fundamental/octave, obviously stable.
- D: pure Pythagorean (9:4) ninth, not a consonance in the usual sense but actually a perfectly smooth interval as long as the bass and melody are far enough apart.
- E: major tenth, extremely consonant if rendered in just intonation (5:2).
- G: fifth/tritave 3:1, easily pure.
- A: major thirteenth/sixth. This one actually works particularly good in the *same* octave as the bass note, namely as the 5:3 major sixth.
- c: yet another octave, duh.

So: those have all frequency ratios with numerator smaller than 10 and denominator <5. In fact, if you list ***all* fractions >1** fulfilling that condition, you find almost *only* notes belonging to the major pentatonic, and only a few out of scale:

- <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — C — fundamental
- <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> — E — third
- **<sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> — F — fourth**
- <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> — G — fifth
- <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> — A — sixth
- **<sup>7</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> — B<sub>₇</sub>♭ — [septimal seventh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_seventh)**
- <sup>2</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — c — octave
- <sup>9</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> — d — ninth
- **<sup>7</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> — e<sub>₇</sub>♭ — [subminor tenth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subminor_and_supermajor#Subminor_third_and_supermajor_sixth)**
- <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> — e — tenth
- **<sup>8</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> — f — eleventh**
- <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — g — twelfth
- **<sup>7</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> — b<sub>₇</sub>♭ — septimal fourteenth**
- <sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — c' — 2 octaves
- <sup>9</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> — d' — 8ve+9th
- <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — e' — 8ve+10th
- <sup>6</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — g' — 8ve<sup>2</sup>+5th
- **<sup>7</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — b<sub>₇</sub>♭' 8ve<sup>2</sup>+₇7th**
- <sup>8</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — c'' — 3 octaves
- <sup>9</sup>⁄<sub>1</sub> — d'' — 8ve<sup>2</sup>+9th

In particular, the range from G to e (which is quite a typical domain for a pentatonic melody) *is exactly the pentatonic scale* if you leave out those foreign 7-limit intervals. The F would of course be a rather natural candidate too, but observe that in my system it only occurs in the low octaves, so it's a more natural choice for the *bass* to jump to (which indeed it often does in folk tunes) rather than the melody.

The septimal seventh is somewhat disqualified in Western music because it can't be approximated by many instruments. This is quite different in many styles around the world.

You may ask what's special about “numerator <10 and denominator <5”. Well, those exact numbers are certainly a bit arbitrary, but actually you will find that the ninth overtone is about the highest that can be reliably played as a flageolett on string instruments. (I believe most brass instruments can also play the 9th overtone fairly well but get into trouble if trying to go much higher, but not sure, I don't play any brass.) Also, three octaves are quite a typical range  “in which most music happens”, traditionally – anything lower or higher is more of a sonic-effect thing.

That's not to say that anything which can't be written as a <10 fraction is necessarily immediately much more consonant. In particular, the 15:8 major seventh is actually a good contender to the 9:8 ninth – in particular, the *major seventh chord* sounds very sweet. But that relies on the proxy-quality of the chord construction: the major seventh can readily be constructed as a third over the fifth in a normal major chord. This kind of construction doesn't really work for a more intuitive, improvisational, single-voice-over-pedal approach.

As for intervals like the 7-limit sevenths, and also slightly higher limits like 11 or 13: those *are* found in some music, in particular Indian, Persian and Arabic music. The problem with these is that if you actually devise tuning systems that allow rendering them on fixed-frequency instruments, you pretty much have to commit to one single key, else it gets very complicated. Western music evolved to also embrace modulations. Those can be nicely incorporated if you only consider the 5-limit intervals, which is probably the reason why we have never found much use of the 7-limit intervals. Except we *have*, actually: the harmonic seventh is all over Barbershop singing, and the subminor third and 7:5 or 11:8 tritones are arguably the prototypical *blue note* intervals. Just, you don't get to write down such intervals exactly in the Western system, so they remain considered as more of an embellishment.

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned that while this pentatonic scale consists of intervals which are all consonant with the tonic C (if you consider 9:8 consonant with 8:8, which is not unreasonable), the interval between the D (9:8) and A (5:3) is the classic wolf fifth, 40:27.

Comment: @ScottWallace indeed. Which adds to the verdict that the pentatonic is mostly a “monophonic scale”, great for freely developing a single voice over a static accompaniment but not all that useful for writing counterpoint.

Comment: yep.  Of course, you can tune your pentatonic scale to equal (or meantone, etc) temperament and smear that wolf over a wide area, but then you are left with no advantage over heptatonicity as far as sound goes, and impoverished in the number of scale steps you have for making effective counterpoint.

Comment: Don't otonal fractions have a denominator being a power of 2?

Comment: @awelotta good point! I actually meant, all fractions >1, not all otonal ones. (Though that would take care of the Fs, but TBH I find otonal vs utonal a bit arbitrary.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably it has to do with the [Pythagorean tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning) as it was used in the development of medieval music.

The tuning is based on the 3:2 ratio (or the perfect fifth), undoubtedly consonant for human ears. The process of stacking fifths upon a fundamental frequency four times generates the scale:

`C G D' A' E''`

Which can be rearranged with octave equivalency to form a pentatonic scale:

`C D E G A`

It works well for the first five notes. Maybe the third would sound considerably higher to our equal-tempered ears, but it was probably fine before equal-temperament was invented (which was not long ago).

The real problem with Pythagorean tuning is that the nice consonance we get for the first five notes is lost for the next two notes (which would make the diatonic scale):

`C G D' A' E'' B'' F'''` or `C D E F G A B`

The relationship of 3:2 between B and F is actually consonant, but from C to F we hear a tritone (as in C - F#), as the fourth is too high (even higher than the third).

So it was probably more common to use pentatonic scales with instruments tuned in Pythagorean method during medieval times, as all intervals would sound consonant.

This might have a direct relationship with Renascence music, as they tend to consider octaves, fifths, sixths and thirds as consonances, but seconds, fourths and sevenths as dissonances. Renascence modality was the basis for baroque's tonality and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are operating under a standard-harmony bias. The pentatonic scale is not a major scale with notes missing it is simply a scale with 5 notes, Penta means 5. It is useful for modern music because its wide intervals make for greater harmonic leeway, but on the other hand, its bare-bones harmony makes it in one sense naked. This is why it often has notes added to it.

It is relevant to the modern genres because, with each new passing of the musical era in the west, there comes a need for the theorist to reinvent the wheel. Now with the pentatonic scales limits in mind, we should still respect it for the big paradigm shift it enabled.

Although I mainly operate under the guise of standard harmony I must say the paradigm shift in music in the 20th century, that was enabled by this scale was a rather brilliant. Jazz, Rock, Blues... all these things take from this piece of harmony. We should all be glad it exists.

Comment: There is nothing "modern" about the pentatonic scale. Western Baroque and Classical music are the exception, rather than the norm, in their avoidance of pentatonic harmonies.

Comment: I like neils answer, @Neil Meyer wasn't native Americans who developed it. Probably just put four evenly spaced wholes for da fingers, so gives 5 notes if you refer the workings of a flute. Then westerners came along, and probably used it for inspiration, to give a new feel that described contemporary America and what better than the music of the Indians they took it from.

Comment: @marshalcraft  _what better than the music of the Indians they took it from_ - Source? Are you saying the African slaves adopated their work songs and chants from the native americans?! AFAIK, It's quite well documented that the pentatonic was absorbed into modern culture through African Americans. IMO the evidence indicates the opposite: traditional American music from whites, although they had more contact with the N-A's than blacks, tends to avoid/minimize pentatonic scales and harmony. Traditional country music, bluegrass etc use decidedly Major/European oriented structures and harmonies.

Comment: @marshalcraft Pentatonic scales existed in the majority of musical cultures, not just in the Americas: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatonic_scale#Pervasiveness Even in Western classical music, pentatonic scales aren't particularly related to "contemporary America".

Answer (score 1):

If you start at C and go up in 5ths and stop after 5 notes (before the M7 interval), that is all of the notes of the pentatonic scale out of order.  C>G>D>A>E
5ths are the most pleasing interval (other than the octave) so you just have one pleasing interval and then it's most pleasing interval and so on til you get 5 notes. Then you can reduce the above notes down by octaves so all notes are within the roots octave range so you get a scale C D E G A (C). That's why it sounds so freakin good, because there isn't an unpleasing note in the bunch.

Comment: You've lost the tritone, that's all. This explanation has been aired many times, and is just co-incidental.

Comment: "You've lost the tritone, that's all." What about the other 6 lost ones?

Comment: You quoted C,D,E,G,A. You must have lost the others somewhere!! They were never in the equation you came up with.

Comment: Yes thank you sir! I will clarify. I intentionally lost the tritone (F#) , including all the other notes but more specifically the 4th (F) and the 7th (B) that was asked about because I stopped after 5 notes since it is a pentatonic scale. They are in the equation, which is the glorious circle of 5ths. C > G > D > A > E > B > F# > C# > G#/Ab > Eb > Bb > F > (C). The beauty is that is is the first 5.

Comment: The phenomenon happens on *any* consecutive five. Take D A E B F#. In 'alphabetic' order, D F# E A B - D maj. pent. So it's not that remarkable. A triton needs two notes, and you didn't lose F#, you lost the F-B/ B-F, which *is* the tritone out of C maj., thus ending up with C pent. maj. pent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the beauty of it working no matter where you start on the circle of fifths. I started on C to stay within the context of the question asked. I must disagree about it being unremarkable because I'm certain that any other person reading this, that was previously unaware, would be rejoicing in their new understanding and finding it quite remarkable for it's pure simplicity in how it relates to the almighty Circle of 5ths, which is rooted in Western music tradition.

Comment: You are all considering equal-tuning system to explain something that it's not necessarily based on it. The idea that the fifth from B is F# exists on our newly developed temperament. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert but I'm surprised no one has mentioned this....

Most articles I have read explain that pentatonic scales are elementary starting scales for students to quickly adapt to any instrument.

Once the student has acquired skillful pentatonic scales, they can complete their training with incorporating the seven note scales.

I believe this method for education purposes would keep their student attentive and practicing, without initially feeling lost.

Comment: Which articles? Could you provide any links?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm. didactic.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2779864/#!po=1.04167

See pentatonic scale‘s last paragraph figure 1

Comment: The article I listed above mentions didactic...

Answer (score 0):

Besides analyzing the theory in an abstract way, it may be useful in this case to take a look at history.

1. Western classical music doesn't really use pentatonic scales at all.
2. Current Western pop music use of pentatonic scales derives from rock music.
3. Rock music's use of pentatonic scales derives from blues.

In other words, so far as Western music is concerned, today's trend of massive use of pentatonic scales in popular music actually originated with the music of American slaves, which lead to various forms of blues (beginning of 20th century) , which in turn heavily influenced rock 'n' roll (50s etc.), which led to the rock music of the 60s and especially the 70s. As rock spread everywhere, pop absorbed more and more elements from it. And one of the key elements that were passed on through all these eras was the use pentatonic scales, especially in instrumental solos and bass lines, and to a slightly lesser extent, song melodies.

Because of this direct line from slaves' songs to modern rock and pop music, I feel that any theoretical analysis of pentatonic scales in themselves runs the risk of being sterile and arbitrary, because it is completely separate from the context in which the tradition was born and grown.

Outside of the Western world, pentatonic scales have a lot of history. Chinese classical music, in particular, is almost completely based on pentatonic scales, and has been so possibly for thousands of years.